# Retrieve SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a column with the following values

```
1. kavitha
2. latha madhu
3. hari prasad
4. kiran
```

I want to retrieve the query such that I want the output to be displayed as kiran. The string which has only one 'A'

Answer (score 1):

You can use like:

```
where name like '%a%' and name not like '%a%a%'
```